# How do I use exiftool to update Lightroom's Hierarchical Subject?

Tags: lightroom, software, metadata, exiftool

I thought this would do it:

```
$ exiftool -XMP:HierarchicalSubject="people|Test" Test.jpg
    1 image files updated

$ exiftool -G -j -n Test.jpg | grep Test
  "SourceFile": "Test.jpg",
  "File:FileName": "Test.jpg",
  "XMP:HierarchicalSubject": "people|Test",
  "XMP:RawFileName": "Test.jpg",
```

But the keyword doesn't show up in Lightroom after reimporting the metadata into Lightroom. How do I make this work?

I don't believe the image will make a difference, but if it does, I'm using [this as the test image](http://www.photoshopsupport.com/photoshop-blog/08/12-cs4/ib-blog/portraiture-bradi1a.jpg).

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about Phil Harvey's ExifTool(http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). If so, have you asked this question on the ExifTool Forum(http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/)? I would assume you would get an audience that is much more familiar with this type of coding then a bunch of photographers here :)

Comment: Does this question still provide any value? The member who asked it, mikj, only visited two days, and has not returned since asking. Should we close this?

Answer (score 1):

This question was re-asked and answered in the ExifTool forum:

http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,3465.0.html

> It looks like LR may be ignoring the XMP in favour of the IPTC.  There are 2 things you can do:
>
> 1) delete all IPTC and use XMP only.  (easy, but not as compatible with other software)
>
> 2) use exiftool to also update the IPTC Keywords and IPTCDigest.  Use "-IPTCDigest=new" to update the Photoshop IPTCDigest whenever you change anything in the IPTC (this is mentioned in the Photoshop tag name documentation).
>
> -- Phil [Harvey, author of ExifTool]

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will not be marked as adv. by moderators but I suggest you to check out our [Daminion](http://daminion.net) to fix your problem with hierarchical keywords. The program is free.

Both Daminion and Lightroom can map tags/keywords to the XMP. So you workflow will be:

- Import your photos to Daminion
- Perform any manipulations with keywords and change their hierarchical structure. This way might be more convenient than interacting with command line utility. Btw we use ExifTool to map the tags/keywords to Camera RAW formats directly without sidecar files.
- Wait a few secs while Daminion automatically syncs your keyword changes back to the XMP
- Re-Import the files back into Lighroom

Really hope this helps